# Add proper syntax name to code blocks when converting from HTML to Markdown with Pandoc

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I need to convert some HTML to Markdown with Pandoc. All is fine except the code blocks in my document are not converted properly. I need them to appear in the resulting Markdown document as backtick-code blocks with syntax definition.

For example, if I have such source HTML:

```html
<pre class="python"><code>
    def myfunc(param):
        '''Description of myfunc'''
        return do_something(param)
</code></pre>
```

I want Pandoc to convert it into:

````
```python
    def myfunc(param):
        '''Description of myfunc'''
        return do_something(param)
```
````

But what I am getting is:

````
``` {.python}
    def myfunc(param):
        '''Description of myfunc'''
        return do_something(param)
```
````

It's almost there, but the syntax definition is in curly braces and with a dot, which is not recognised by my Markdown parser. **How can I get  ```` ```python ```` instead of  ```` ``` {.python} ```` when converting HTML to Markdown?**

I have control over the source HTML, so I can change it the way needed. If there's an option to insert "raw markdown" into the HTML which will be ignored by Pandoc, that would work for me too, I can embed those blocks into the source HTML the way I need, but I need to tell Pandoc not to touch them. But I can't find such option in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is governed by the [`fenced_code_attributes`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-fenced_code_attributes) extension. It is enabled by default; disabling it will give your desired output:

```
pandoc --to=markdown-fenced_code_attributes ...
```